# Theme Option's Save Button is not working

Tags: theme-development, theme-options, options, customization

I'm currently working on making an options panel for a theme (theme-options.php) on my localhost.  Every thing was going well until I tried testing the Save button.  After clicking it, I got the message that the options were saved but nothing actually saved.  Not sure if this matters, but theme-options.php is located in a folder named "options" in the theme's home directory.  Here is the current function I'm using for saving:

```
//add options page
function fround_add_admin(){
    global $themename, $shortname, $options;

    if ( $_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__) ){

        if ( 'save' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
            //protect against request forgery
            check_admin_referer('theme-save');

            //save the options
            foreach ($options as $value) {
                if( isset( $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ) ) {
                    update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] );
                } else {
                    delete_option( $value['id'] );
                }
            }

            header("Location: themes.php?page=theme-options.php&saved=true");
            die;

        } else if ( 'reset' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
            //protect against request forgery
            check_admin_referer('theme-reset');
            //delete the options
            foreach ($option as $value) {
                delete_option( $value['id'] );
            }

            header("Location: themes.php?page=theme-options.php&reset=true");
            die;
        }
    }
    add_theme_page($themename." Options", "$themename Options", 'edit_themes', basename(__FILE__), 'fround_admin');
}
add_action('admin_menu' , 'fround_add_admin');
```

I'm following a tutorial to make this panel (with a couple modifications to my needs) and everything looks the same as in the tutorial.  Looking through it with the php knowledge I have, I see nothing wrong either.  Here's the entire theme-options.php:

```
<?php

//theme vars
$themename = "f Round";
$shortname = "fround";
$options = array();

function theme_options(){
    global $themename, $shortname, $options;

    $options = array (

        array("name" => "General Settings",
            "type" => "section"),
        array("type" => "open"),

        array("name" => "Type of Logo",
            "desc" => "Select your logo type ( Image or Text )",
            "id" => $shortname."_type_of_logo",
            "type" => "select",
            "options" => array("text", "logo"),
            "std" => "text"),

        array("name" => "Logo Upload",
            "desc" => "Upload images using the native media uploader, or define the URL directly",
            "id" => $shortname."_logo_upload",
            "type" => "imageupload",
            "std" => ""),

        array("name" => "Logo Text",
            "desc" => "Enter text for logo",
            "id" => $shortname."_logo_text",
            "type" => "text",
            "std" => ""),

        array("name" => "Logo Slogan",
            "desc" => "Enter text for logo slogan",
            "id" => $shortname."_logo_slogan",
            "type" => "text",
            "std" => ""),

        array("name" => "Custom Favicon",
            "desc" => "Upload a 16px x 16px Png/Gif image that will represent your website's favicon",
            "id" => $shortname."_favicon_upload",
            "type" => "imageupload",
            "std" => ""),

        array("type" => "close"),
        array("name" => "Styling Options",
            "type" => "section"),
        array("type" => "open"),

        array("name" => "Background Color",
            "desc" => "Pick a color for the background",
            "id" => $shortname."_background_color",
            "type" => "color",
            "std" => "#ffffff"),

        array("name" => "Body Color",
            "desc" => "Pick a color for the body",
            "id" => $shortname."_body_color",
            "type" => "color",
            "std" => "#ffffff"),

        array("type" => "close"),
        array("name" => "Footer Options",
            "type" => "section"),
        array("type" => "open"),

        array("name" => "Copyright Text",
            "desc" => "Enter text for copyright in footer (if empty it will be removed)",
            "id" => $shortname."_footer_text",
            "type" => "text",
            "std" => "Copyright TestSite.com"),

        array("type" => "close")

    );
}
add_action('init', 'theme_options');

//add options page
function fround_add_admin(){
    global $themename, $shortname, $options;

    if ( $_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__) ){

        if ( 'save' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
            //protect against request forgery
            check_admin_referer('theme-save');

            //save the options
            foreach ($options as $value) {
                if( isset( $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ) ) {
                    update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] );
                } else {
                    delete_option( $value['id'] );
                }
            }

            header("Location: themes.php?page=theme-options.php&saved=true");
            die;

        } else if ( 'reset' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
            //protect against request forgery
            check_admin_referer('theme-reset');
            //delete the options
            foreach ($option as $value) {
                delete_option( $value['id'] );
            }

            header("Location: themes.php?page=theme-options.php&reset=true");
            die;
        }
    }
    add_theme_page($themename." Options", "$themename Options", 'edit_themes', basename(__FILE__), 'fround_admin');
}
add_action('admin_menu' , 'fround_add_admin');

//main function
function fround_admin() {
    global $themename, $shortname, $options;

    //saved or reset messages
    if ( $_REQUEST['saved'] ) echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>'.$themename.' settings saved.</strong></p></div>';
    if ( $_REQUEST['reset'] ) echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>'.$themename.' settings reset.</strong></p></div>';

    //form
    ?>
    <header>
        <h1><?php echo $themename; ?></h1>
    </header>

    <aside>
        <nav>
            <ul>
            <?php
            foreach ($options as $value){
                switch ( $value['type'] ){
                    case 'section':
                        echo '<li><a>'.$value['name'].'</li></a>';
                        break;
                }
            }
            ?>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </aside>

    <form method="post">
        <?php wp_nonce_field('theme-save'); ?>

        <main>
        <?php
            foreach ($options as $value){
                switch ( $value['type'] ){
                    case 'section':
                        ?>
                        <section name="<?php echo $value['name'];?>">
                            <h3><?php echo $value['name'];?></h3>
                        <?php
                        break;

                    case 'open':
                        break;

                    case 'close':
                        ?>
                        </section>
                        <?php
                        break;

                    case 'select':
                        ?>
                        <div id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" class="option <?php echo $value['type']; ?>">
                            <select>
                                <?php
                                foreach ($value['options'] as $option){
                                    echo '<option value="'.$option.'">'.$option.'</option>';
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>

                            <p><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></p>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        break;

                    case 'text':
                        ?>
                        <div id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" class="option <?php echo $value['type']; ?>">
                            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $value['std']; ?>">

                            <p><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></p>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        break;

                    case 'imageupload':
                        ?>
                        <div id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" class="option <?php echo $value['type']; ?>">

                            <p><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></p>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        break;

                    case 'color':
                        ?>
                        <div id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" class="option <?php echo $value['type']; ?>">

                            <p><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></p>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        break;
                }
            }
        ?>
        </main>

        <p class="submit">
            <input name="save" type="submit" value="Save changes" class="button-primary" />
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save" />
        </p>
    </form>

    <form method="post">
        <?php wp_nonce_field('theme-reset'); ?>
        <p class="submit">
            <input name="reset" type="submit" value="Reset changes" />
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="reset" />
        </p>
    </form>
    <?php
}
?>
```

What exactly am I doing wrong for the save button not to work?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I changed the 'select' and 'text' cases to the following (which still isn't working for me):

```
case 'select':
?>
<div id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" class="option <?php echo $value['type']; ?>">
    <select>
        <?php
        foreach ($value['options'] as $key=>$option){
            if ($key == get_option($value['id'], $value['std']) ) {
                $selected = 'selected="selected"';
            } else{
                $selected = "";
            }
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>" <?php echo $selected ?>><?php echo $option; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>

    <p><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></p>
</div>
<?php
break;

case 'text':
?>
<div id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" class="option <?php echo $value['type']; ?>">
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo stripslashes( get_option($value['id'], $value['std']) ); ?>">

    <p><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></p>
</div>
<?php
break;
```

I'm going to continue working on this but some help would still be much appreciated.

Comment: May i suggest you edit out the profanity from your sample code.

Comment: Okay all edited out, sorry.  I also made a few changes to my code (shown above) but it's still not working.

Comment: this is a bit of an odd way to create a theme options system, perhaps the tutorial you followed predates the [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API), which simplifies a lot of the details.

Comment: Yea I was just looking through a tutorial that used that now: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/how-to-integrate-the-wordpress-media-uploader-in-theme-and-plugin-options/  But yea I'm learning from the Build Your Own Wicked Wordpress Themes book from SitePoint.  Any reason why this doesn't work though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've started rewriting everything using the Settings API and everything is working well now.